# Bash case statement to create file

Tags: bash, shell, touch, case

Hello i am creating a simple case statement menu to implement an address book and i am having trouble.

the menu work fine but i am having trouble understanding why the file is not created through this command.

this is just primary testing to see if a file is created but is is giving me an operand error so i tried adding .txt to the end and it gave no feedback.

```
 1) echo "Please enter a name for your addressbook"
                        read addName
                        touch $addname

                break;;
```

Comment: Variable names are case sensitive..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this.

```
echo "Please enter a name for your addressbook"
                        read addName
                        touch $addName.txt

                break;;
```

for a text file.

Comment: And that changes nothing.

Comment: filenames of themselves have absolutely nothing to do with their contents. Just using a ".txt" extension does not force the OS to give the file any specific properties.

Answer (score 2):

`read addName` vs. `$addname`  The names are not the same (uppercase n vs. lowercase n)